# How to set p-checkbox to checked and store the selection object to list

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have the list like below:

```
rows: any[] = [
   {"id":"1721079361", "type":"0002", "number":"2100074912","checked":true},
   {"id":"1721079365", "type":"0003", "number":"2100074913","checked":false},
   {"id":"1721079364", "type":"0004", "number":"2100074914","checked":true},
   {"id":"1721079362", "type":"0001", "number":"2100074911", "checked":false}
];
```

And I want to display on the table with the checkbox
[image]

I want to the checkbox is checked if the checked value = true, and these items are checked should be stored on a list.
Here is [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ddptg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Please advise me

Answer (score 2):

use `binary` property:

```
<p-checkbox
                [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" value="{{row.id}}"

                binary="{{row.checked?'1':''}}"

                ></p-checkbox>
```

it is not important what you write instead of `1` in the written expression. because it uses string map of javascript boolean values:

• in javascript empty string is `false` and non-empty string is `true`